# How to add command with : to config

Tags: neovim, command

The command `:LongLines` comes from the plugin manu-mannattil/vim-longlines. How can I include it in my Neovim config, so it is executed every time the program starts?

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
autocmd VimEnter * LongLines
```

You can't simply add `LongLines` to your `.vimrc` since the plugin is not loaded at that moment and that is why you need a `autocomand`.

But in my tests with the long lines plugin it seems that the long line status is more a buffer attribute than a global attribute and to make it work by default to the buffer the following settings works better:

```
autocmd VimEnter * LongLines
autocmd FileType * LongLines
```

The total should be something like:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'manu-mannattil/vim-longlines'
call plug#end()

autocmd VimEnter * LongLines
autocmd FileType * LongLines
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Welcome to Vim :-) If the answer solves your problem mark it as accepted by using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons.

Comment: May I ask, why did you use `au` in the first line and `autocmd` in the second?

Comment: It is strange but these settings do not work. `" Plugin to help navigate through long soft-wrapped lines Plug 'manu-mannattil/vim-longlines' au VimEnter * LongLines autocmd FileType * LongLines`. When I manually type `:LongLines`, the setting begins to work in all buffers, though.

Comment: `au` is a shortcut for`autocmd`